# how to change the method of boost::asio::ssl::context

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, boost-asio

I'm writing a https server for a third part client application. I'm using **pion** c++ network library to implement the server,

The tricky thing is that: the client uses **sslv2** but pion uses **sslv23** as the context method. This is the constructor:

```
server::server(...)
    : .....
    m_ssl_context(m_active_scheduler.get_io_service(),
                        boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23), // <--- not configurable
    ....
{}
```

I understand there is security issue with sslv2 so pion uses sslv23 as default, but the client uses **sslv2** only. With the **sslv23**, the server complains "**unknown protocol**" during the handshake.

I don't want to modify the pion source to make it support only **sslv2**. I can get the underlying **ssl::context** object, how can I modify it to support **sslv2**?

I looked into **boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp**, the ssl::context is **noncopyable**, and no helper function can be used with that.

Any idea?

Thanks.

**UPDATE_1**:

here's some test

**test 1**:

I modified pion source and recompiled it, just comment out the **no_sslv2** line

```
    m_ssl_context.set_options(
        boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds
        //| boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2 <------ remove this
        | boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);
```

and leave it use sslv23 (there're four sslv23 in constructors)

```
server::server(...)
    : .....
    m_ssl_context(m_active_scheduler.get_io_service(),
                        boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23), // left it as sslv23
    ....
{}
```

it doesn't work, boost error_code.message() :

```
peer error no cipher
```

**test 2**:

if I don't touch the no_sslv2

```
    m_ssl_context.set_options(
        boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds
        | boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2 <------
        | boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);
```

and change the four sslv23 to sslv2

```
server::server(...)
    : .....
    m_ssl_context(m_active_scheduler.get_io_service(),
                        boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv2), // change from sslv23 to sslv2
    ....
{}
```

then it works fine. I guess it's the sslv23 method in constructor that actually matters. In the context's constructor:

```
context::context(context::method m)
  : handle_(0)
{
  switch (m)
  {
  ...
  case context::sslv2:
    handle_ = ::SSL_CTX_new(::SSLv2_method());
    break;
  ...
  case context::sslv23:
    handle_ = ::SSL_CTX_new(::SSLv23_method());
    break;
  }
  ....
}
```

SSLv23_method is not compatible with SSLv2_method?

And I think the client use sslv2 because I tested it with openssl:

**test 3**:

```
openssl s_server -accept 443 -key server.pem -cert server.pem -ssl2
```

This makes openssl act as server, then connect the client to it, it works fine. According to openssl's doc, the trailing **-ssl2** force it use sslv2. And neither **-ssl3** nor **-tls1** works, openssl says: "wrong version number"

**UPDATE_2**

I tried this, seems also works, don't know if it would cause memory leak.

```
    SSL_CTX_set_ssl_version( // use the native handle
        m_server_443->get_ssl_context_type().native_handle(), ::SSLv2_method()
    );
```

Comment: As rhashimoto answered, the problem is *not* with the `SSLv23_method`. That's actually the way to build a context. You start with the 2/3 method, and then you take away what you don't want, like SSLv2, SSLv3 and Compression. See, for example, [SSL/TLS Client](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not in the construction of `m_ssl_context` that you show. The specification of `ssl::context::sslv23` means that your server accepts SSLv2 or higher to begin negotiating the secure connection. The restriction that disallows SSLv2 is in the same file but after that:

```
m_ssl_context.set_options(boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds
                          | boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2
                          | boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);
```

It's the `ssl::context::no_sslv2` option that is rejecting SSLv2 connections.

You may be able to reset those options like this:

```
SSL_CTX_clear_options(m_server->get_ssl_context_type().native_handle(), SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2)
SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(m_server->get_ssl_context_type().native_handle(), "TLSv1:SSLv3:SSLv2");
```

These two lines use the underlying OpenSSL API to (1) clear the `no_sslv2` option that is set in the `set_ssl_key_file()` member function, and (2) ensure that the SSLv2 ciphers are enabled. Using the `set_options()` member function does not work because it cannot clear a previously set option so the OpenSSL API function `SSL_CTX_clear_options()` must be used.

It's odd that you have a client that only uses SSLv2 as this protocol has been deprecated as insecure for a very long time (nearly 20 years!).

Comment: @aj3423 I think you can make `SSLv23_method` work without modifying the library source. The "no cipher" error message means that handshaking was working but the client and server couldn't agree on a cipher. I suspect that by default OpenSSL doesn't accept very many of the SSLv2 ciphers unless you explicitly ask for SSLv2. Try adding a call like `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(m_server_443->get_ssl_context_type().native_handle(), "TLSv1:SSLv3:SSLv2");` (in addition to the `set_options()` call). This will allow all the ciphers from those three protocols.

Comment: I tried `set_ssl_key_file` -> `set_options` -> `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list`, seems not working, the error message is "unknown protocol"

Comment: @aj3423 Ah, the [doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__context/set_options/overload1.html) says, "The options are bitwise-ored with any existing value for the options." So once `no_sslv2` is set it seems like there is no way to unset it with the Boost API. You'll have to do something with the OpenSSL API like `SSL_CTX_clear_options(m_server_443->get_ssl_context_type().native_handle(), SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2)`.

Comment: That's the key. It works with `SSL_CTX_clear_options` + `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list`. Thank you very much rhashimoto.